# orientation of react native app doesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, orientation, react-native

The rotation of the app works in three of four cases. If I hold the ipad **not** edgewise with the home button at the bottom, the app adjusts correctly. But if I rotate the ipad in the edgewise (home button on bottom) position, the app remains in the last orientation. Thus the portrait view works correctly but just if the home button is on the top. Any ideas?

Comment: what exactly want to ask ?

Comment: how to fix this. what else?

Answer (score -1):

Please, check the following answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057998/2382237

According to it, You should override this methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Maybe it can help you to figure out what is wrong

Comment: At the risk of appearing like a newbie (yes I am a newbie): Which file I have to edit and where can I find it? Note: I'm new to React Native and I don't have any plan of Objective C. greez

Comment: this code for your viewController, where you need to handle orientation changes